# reflect light beam of disco ball EEVEE

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, reflection

I'm trying to make, what should think to be an easy job for blender, a disco mirror ball. And I want to have the beam of a spotlight reflect in to tiny beams of the ball...as it does in real life.

I tried making the mirrorball glossy with roughness 0 and played around with various volumetric lighting settings in EEVEE ( I've seen lots of tutorials online ) 
But I just can't get the job done. The beam simply does not reflect...

Any pointers?

Comment: Those are reflective caustics and volumetrics - they are definitely not supposed to be an easy job. You could try to imitate the reflections by emitiing light from the ball.

Comment: Could you share some reference images of the effect that you are working with?

Comment: This is impossible with a rasterization engine. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html

Comment: FFeller, it's impossible to *simulate* somewhat accurately. It might still be possible to fake the effect and get acceptable results.